# How do I get rid of type lacking in the Anaconda Spyder editor?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I use Spyder (Anaconda) a lot as my IDE for Python, but unfortunately it has practically become useless because whenever I type anything in the editor, the text is lagging a lot. There is a delay of around half a second or more. This is super annoying, and I haven't got any idea how to solve it. I've searched the internet, and I can see that other people have the same issue, but I haven't managed to solve it. Even if I reinstall Anaconda and Spyder, it does not help me.

I'm working on a Macbook with the system macOS Monterey, and my Anaconda is version 2.1.1 and Spyder is 5.1.5. My Macbook is from 2017 and works perfectly fine.

Has anybody got a clue about how this can be fixed?

Comment: Spyder Properties or if you are also running Kite look in Kite properties.  Look for control related to code completion

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please use our app for macOS, which can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases). That shouldn't show such big lags as the ones you're describing.

Comment: Thanks you Carlos Cordoba, the problem is resolved after downloading the app!

Comment: Carlos, any chance of releasing a version for Aarch MacOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the app directly from the link below and the lacking will disappear!

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases